# Meteor Sass using base sass from deeper files

Tags: meteor, sass

I've got a Meteor project with the following file structure:

```
.meteor
client
  dashboard
    dashboard.scss
  client.scss
```

My basic sass file is client.scss that resides in client folder.

If I define $flat-button in client.scss. Then I cannot use it in dashboard.css without adding `import '../client';`. However when I do this in multiple files this causes duplicate entries in the unified css file. If I don't import it then Meteor reports errors due to not finding the variable.

Should I add settings to the sass compiler to get this working?

Comment: I don't see the problem here?  If you need the variable to be accessible elsewhere, then define it elsewhere or change the order of your imports.

Comment: The whole point of having a base sass file is that I don't want to redeclare my colors in every subfile. And I don't have any influence on the import order as far as I know.

Comment: And you can't create a *new* file that contains only variables?

Comment: Sure I can, but then I'd have to import that file to get it working. And to my understanding Meteor glues together all scss files to one css file. So if i import that file in 3 other files, then meteor glues 4 copies of colors.scss together in the deployment.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the [`fourseven:scss`](https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss) package to compile the Sass in your Meteor project, you simply need to prefix the filenames of your imported `.scss` files with an underscore, which is [the standard method of naming a partial stylesheet with Sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials).

In your case, your folder and file structure should be changed to:

```
.meteor
  client
    dashboard
      _dashboard.scss
    client.scss
```

And then you should be able to use an `@import` statement to include `_dashboard.scss` in `client.scss` like so:

```
@import 'dashboard'
```

If for some reason you don't want to rename your files that way, you can also use the `.scssimport` extension for the same result.

Hope that helps!